# DynamoDB with sort Key very very slow

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using dynamoDB to store some basic data (Bitcoin, Litecoin and other cryptocurrencies prices).

Here is what I've done, that seems to make sense according to DynamoDB documentation and my researches :

- Partition Key : "Bitcoin"
- Sort key : xxxxxxxx (the timestamp of the data, every minute)

This way I can query the data for the Bitcoin, between this date and this date which is exactly what I want.

But the problem is I've stored 30000 items yet, and **it already takes 3 seconds to query** ! I'm planning in adding millions of items, so it does'nt look right.

Do I need to add another Index ? Or is my schema wrong ?

Here is my query

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'crypto',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#id = :idcrypto and #timestamp between :timestamp_from and :timestamp_to',
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#id": "id",
        "#timestamp": "timestamp"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
        ':idcrypto': "BITCOIN" ,
        ':timestamp_from': timestamp_from,
        ':timestamp_to': timestamp_to 
        
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is the way you do it. I have some suggestions for you. The first one is to check on the filter expression to query data between a range. The second one is when you're querying make sure you're not crossing the limit of 1 MB or else you have to perform the query again. The last one is it is advisable to use other services ( Not Dynamodb) for these types of problems.

Comment: what is the timeframe that you use for a query that takes 3 seconds? I mean, how many results does it fetch?

Comment: The query that takes 3 seconds returns 1500 items. So if this 1500 items are more than 1MB all together, dynamodb queried more than once is this correct ?

Comment: @Francois I meant you should keep on querying to get all the data. Whenever you are querying data of size greater than 1 MB you won't get all the required data. So you need to query till you get the whole data

Comment: I suggest AWS timestream for this, it is meant for storing a large amount of data in such rate.